# issue using jquery.load() and url.Action using multiple parrameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, helper, jquery-load

i have the next function:

```
    $('#show-modal').click(function () {
        $('#my-dialog').load("@Url.Action("_BuscarPersona", "Persona", new { target = "#idtest", tipoPredefinido = 0 })", function () {
            $(this).dialog('open');
        });
    });
```

the problem im having is that utl.Action is changing the `&` to `&amp` on the url, so my controller wont find any method match.

```
http://localhost:3456/Persona/_BuscarPersona?target=%23idtest&amp;tipoPredefinido=0
```

any know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not your Url.Action escaping this chars?

Comment: yep, u are rigth, updating my Q

Answer (score 0):

well ended up doing this:

```
    $('#show-modal').click(function () {
        $('#my-dialog').load("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("_BuscarPersona", "Persona", new { target= "#idtest", tipoPredefinido= 0 }))", function () {
            $(this).dialog('open');
        });
    });
```

but it dosnt looks nice